# I getting error when deploying the TableForm

Tags: cloud-deploy, databin

```
vlabs = {0 -> "0", 1 -> "1", 2 -> "2"};
TableForm[{{"Java", RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[t1], vlabs]}, {"Pyhton",
 RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[t2], vlabs]}, {"CSS", 
 RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[t3], vlabs]}, 
 Button["Save",
  DatabinAdd[
  Databin["----"], {{"seher", {"java", t1}, {"pyhton", t2}, {"CSS",t3}}}]]}]
```

When I run this code on the Worksheet It's saving my datas to the databin.
[image: When I run this on the Worksheet It's saving my datas to the databin.]

But however when I deploy it with CloudDeploy function and click the save button I see this page:
[image]

What can be the problem? Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

```
vlabs = {0 -> "0", 1 -> "1", 2 -> "2"};
TableForm[{{"Java", RadioButtonBar[t1, vlabs]}, {"Pyhton",
 RadioButtonBar[t2, vlabs]}, {"CSS", 
 RadioButtonBar[t3, vlabs]}, 
 Button["Save",
  DatabinAdd[
   Databin["----"], {{"seher", {"java", t1}, {"pyhton", t2}, {"CSS",t3}}}]]}]
```

When I remove the Dynamics it worked. I think making the buttons dynamic was creating an error.